# Uniform distributed variable X:U(-9,9) is given. Find the CDF of Y if Y is..

Tags: probability, integration, random-variables

$$Y= \begin{cases} 4X,\ \ \  |X| \leq 3 \\ 0,\ \ \ \ \ \ |X|>3 \end{cases}$$

My take on it:

$$F_Y(y)=0; y\leq-12;F_Y(y)=1; y\geq 12;$$

$$F_Y(y)=\{Y < y \}$$

In class in a similar task we drew the functions and integrated in relation to the graph with respect to dx and the given density function. What I am having trouble is finding the boundaries of the integral...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that the pdf of $X$ is
$$f_X(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{18},&\text{ if } -9\le x \le 9\\
\ 0,& \text{ otherwise. }\end{cases}$$
We can treat $F_Y(y)=P(Y<y)$ as the sum of two probabilities:

$$F_Y(y)=P(Y<y\cap |X|>3)+P(Y<y\cap |X|\le 3).$$
First,
$$P(Y<y\cap |X|>3)=P(0<y \cap |X|>3)=\begin{cases}
0,&\text{ if } y<0\\
P(|X|>3)=\frac{2}{3},&\text{ if } y\ge 0.
\end{cases}$$
Second,
$$P(Y<y\cap |X|\le 3)=P(X<\frac{y}{4}\cap -3\le X \le 3)=\begin{cases}
0,&\text{ if }& y<-12\\
\frac{1}{72}y+\frac{1}{6},&\text{ if }& -12\le y\le12\\
\frac{1}{3},&\text{ if }& y> 12.\\
\end{cases}$$

Actually your integral is hiding above behind the function
$$\frac{1}{72}y+\frac{1}{6}=\int_{-3}^{y/4}f_X(x)dx=\frac{1}{18}[x]_{-3}^{y/4}.$$ 
So, the sum of the two probabilities gives

$$F_Y(y)=\begin{cases}
0,&\text{ if }& y<-12\\
\frac{1}{72}y+\frac{1}{6},&\text{ if }& -12\le y< 0\\\frac{1}{72}y+\frac{5}{6},&\text{ if }& 0\le y\le 12\\
1,&\text{ if }& y> 12.\\
\end{cases}$$

Below is the graph of $F_Y(y)$
[image]

Comment: --Thanks a lot !

Comment: If you accept (any of the) answers, please click on the corresponding check mark button.

Comment: This is very good work. Thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that $Y$ takes values in $(-12,12)$ and "mainly" uniformly. However,
this is a 'mixed' distribution with positive probability at the
point $0$. So you are not going to find a PDF for $Y$. Think
it through in terms of intervals of $X$ in order to get the CDF of $Y.$

If you have ready access to R, you might run the following code for
a (necessarily crude, possibly helpful) histogram.

```
 x = runif(10^5, -9, 9);  y = 4*x;  y[abs(x)>3]=0
 hist(y, prob=T, br=50)
```

Comment: I honestly don;t know what hist, or runit is, could you type it out if its not a problem, would apreciate. :)

Comment: Ive not done this, i can only used a paper and pen to traditionally like the old mathematicians did write out the answer formally..

Comment: The statement 'runif' generates 100,000 iid variates from UNIF(0,1). The third statement sets a huge chunk of those 100,000 variates to 0. The 'hist' function makes a histogram of the 100,000 values of Y; argument 'prob=T' asks for a 'density' scale instead of a frequency scale; argument 'br' forces 50 histogram bins instead of the usual smaller number of bins. But I'm afraid this won't help much if you don't have R. The code would run whether or not you understand the statements. (R is available free from r.project.org) _But you really can think it through without the help of software._

Comment: Hey, thanks for that. I have no doubt it will become useful later on do I continue to pursue this field. :)

Comment: Histogram looks like UNIF(-12,12) but area under 'density' is not 1. Histogram also indicates a spike at 0--a single value with all of
the probability missing from the 'density'. Between -12 and 12, your CDF will have two linear pieces interrupted by a jump at 0. Neither a strictly continuous nor a strictly discrete distribution: "mixture" dist'n.